# Why is encumbranceByType object possible undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I have a react component that takes in data of type `EncumbranceData[]` and restructures that data before mapping through it. This restructuring involves creating an empty object of type `EncumbrancesByType` and creating keys and values for it based on `encumbranceData`

However, I keep getting an "Object possible undefined" error where it says `encumbrancesByType[e.type].push(e.suite)`. I don't understand how this could be undefined, as none of the fields on these types are optional. This component will always receive data of type `EncumbranceData` that will always have a type, id, and suite. `EncumbranceData` cannot be undefined. The object starts as an empty one, but each iteration through the `forEach` method should initialize each key with a truthy empty array.

How can the object possible be undefined, then, at the `push(e.suite)` statement?

I can get it to work by just using a bunch of optional operators (`encumbrancesByType?.push()`), but I feel like that defeats the point of type safety.

```js
type EncumbranceData = {
  id: string;
  suite: string;
  type: string;
};

interface EncumbrancesByType {
  [key: string]: string[];
}

type EncumbranceAlertByTypeProps = {
  id: string;
  suites: string[];
  type: string;
};

const EncumbranceAlertByType: React.FC<EncumbranceAlertByTypeProps> = ({ id, suites, type }) => {
  const renderSuites = suites.map((s) => <span>{s}</span>);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{type}</div>
      {renderSuites}
    </div>
  );
};

type ConflictingEncumbrancesAlertProps = {
  encumbranceData: EncumbranceData[];
  isOpen: boolean;
  onContinue(): void;
  onCancel(): void;
  suiteIdsToCheck: string[];
  encumbranceTypesToConsider?: EncumbranceType[];
};

const ConflictingEncumbrancesAlert: React.FC<ConflictingEncumbrancesAlertProps> = ({
  encumbranceData,
  isOpen,
  onContinue,
  onCancel,
  suiteIdsToCheck,
  encumbranceTypesToConsider,
}) => {

  const encumbrancesByType: EncumbrancesByType = {}
  encumbranceData.forEach((e) => {
    if (!encumbrancesByType[e.type]) encumbrancesByType[e.type] = [e.suite]
    else encumbrancesByType[e.type].push(e.suite)
  })

  const encumbrancesContent = Object.keys(encumbrancesByType).map((type) => (
    <EncumbranceAlertByType suites={encumbrancesByType[type]} type={type} />
  ));

  return <div>{encumbrancesContent}</div>;
};

export default ConflictingEncumbrancesAlert;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have the [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) rule enable in your `tsconfig`. When you have this rule the compiler will always complain on unchecked index access.

Also, TS won't narrow down (remove the `undefined`) on index access. In order to have the compiler do that, you'll have to use an intermidiate variable.

```
encumbranceData.forEach((e) => {
  const foo = encumbrancesByType[e.type]; // intermediate variable
  if (foo) {
    foo.push(e.suite); // ok 
  }
});
```

[Playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgYwK4FsBGAnAhoiARLYLKAXigG8BYAKCigEsATALigGdgN64BzAbhp02SesAisOXXgNpRQkCZ278aAXxk1uYjADMsCaPGTpsuNgCEQAFXDQqsgNoBrCCEVSeAXXfKHnmao0QdSMEAgANlgY0AgA9nAcUBCIqJg4BgRErEapphmEWH4a1DRxCcBJKSbpEBbWttlVaWaWNpCkFOo0ycbN%20UQAdDqxGDD6ABYAFJMQAJSkAHwUglBlicOxHT25NXVtEA4QA-IQ-iv0OlCTG-P2dHQbA2BIbFNHwqJzMnSB1KqzMiAA)

Comment: This is it, thank you. Follow up question - the `suites` prop on the `EncumbranceAlertByType` component is possibly undefined as well. Why might the compiler be saying this prop could be undefined if nothing else before it can be?

Comment: It's the same rule that is reminding you that `suites` could be undefined as it is defined by an indexed access !